# Way to sort results from AtTask / WorkFront API?

Tags: api, attask, workfront-api

Is there a way to sort or order the results from the AtTask / WorkFront web API? I didn't see a way in the API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort results from the api by appending _Sort=asc.
For example if you want to sort by name you can pass the following parameter in your query.
name_Sort=asc